# pytest exec code in self.locals SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'exec'

Tags: python, pycharm, pytest

Trying to debug a pytest unit test gives me

> exec code in self.locals SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to
>   'exec'

on very simple code.

What could be causing it?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Don't have a package/directory/file/module named `code` in your code, because it conflicts with pytest.

Changing to `src` solved this.

I found the answer [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360003754139/comments/360000648220):

> it turned out to be a conflict with my own python module called 'code'
> and one in use by the debugger. I changed my module name and the
> debugger began working. This article pointed me to the solution:
> https://superuser.com/questions/1385995/my-pycharm-run-is-working-but-debugging-is-failing

This took me a while to find, so I thought I'd post it here for easy googling.

Comment: you would have thought that pycharm IDE would warn about having a code.py file.

Comment: @Konchog not sure now but I think it was a package and not a file. maybe all are problematic

Comment: maybe so - but I had the same problem as you described b/c I ‘foolishly’ called my main file code.py